# How to update data on event between components in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working with two parallel `angular2` components and trying to update data in component-2 on click of component-1.

Here's the code:

**shared service:**

```
class updateData {
  constructor (){
    this._req = {};
    this.observer;
    this.updateReq = new Rx.Observable(function (observer) {
              return this.observer = observer;
    }).share();
  }
  update(req) {
    this._req = req;
    this.observer.next(req);
  }
};
```

Component 1:

```
app.getLogs = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'get-logs',
    providers: [updateData, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS, httpService],
    template: "<button class='btn btn-success pull-left mrT2' (click)='getLogfilters()' >Get Logs</button>"
  })

  .Class({
    constructor: [updateData,ng.http.Http, httpService, function (updateData, http, service){
      this.result = {};
      this.http = http;
      this.service = service;
      this.updateData = updateData;
      this.reqBody = {};
    }],

    getLogfilters: function(){
      var fed = (function(){
        return this;
      }).bind(this);

      setTimeout(function(){
        var self = fed();
        self.service.getLogs(req, selectedCompany).subscribe(function(result){
          this.result = JSON.parse(result._body);

          //--------- UPDATE DATA HERE--------------//
          self.updateData.update(req);

        }.bind(this), function(error){
          error = JSON.parse(error._body);
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        });

      });
    }
  });
```

Component 2:

```
app.AuditLogs =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'audit-logs',
      providers: [updateData, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS, httpService],
      templateUrl: '/public/webapp/ng2/audit_logs/audit-logs.html',
    })
    .Class({
      constructor:[updateData,ng.http.Http, httpService, function(updateData, http, service) {
        this.result = {};
        this.http = http;
        this.logs = [];
        this.updateData = updateData;

        // --------- CATCH UPDATED DATA HERE ---------- //
        this.updateData.updateReq.subscribe(function (req) { 
           console.log(req);
        });
      }]
  });
```

Whenever I click on **component 2** and try to run this I get an error:

> "Cannot read property 'next' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

`this` in

```
this.updateReq = new Rx.Observable(function (observer) {
          return this.observer = observer;
}).share();
```

isn't what you expect because of

```
`function (observer)` in
```

either change it to

```
(observer) =>
```

or to

```
this.updateReq = new Rx.Observable(function (observer) {
          return this.observer = observer;
}.bind(this)).share();
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I didn't look further. This is probably required to more of your `function () ...`. Usually you want to use `=>` everywhere anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :), I m trying to figure it out.